# Handle cache if multiple requests come for same key in case of LFU

Tags: java, caching, concurrency, operating-system

I need to design Least frequently used(LFU) cache. I will store the count and timestamp. So that if count will be same then cache will remove the entry on the basis of timestamp.

Now I have one problem, If multiple requests(Number is too high) will come at the same time for the same key. How will i manage the cache(count and timestamp for that key)?  If i'll make it synchronise then it will become slow. I want to make it fast.

Comment: So you want to create a high performance cache but you don't know how? In that case, don't bother. Get an existing tried and true cache, and use that.

Comment: Could you please let me know which inbuilt cache will work in this case properly?

Comment: I think all of them will work *properly*, but if you want to compare their features and performance, you'll have to do your own research.

Comment: I provide a lot of background material on the design of [Caffeine](https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine). The policy and concurrency model are described in this [HighScalability article](http://highscalability.com/blog/2016/1/25/design-of-a-modern-cache.html)